# Open Window in tab on Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am using following code to open window in new tab, and it is working on IE and Mozilla. but it's didn't worked on Google Chrome. Code is:

```
    <script language="javascript">
        window.open('viewReport.aspx', '_newtab' );
    </script>
```

Above code is inside div and When I set div is visible true it is open a new tab window on IE and Mozilla.
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: `<script language="javascript">` — why are you using HTML 3.2 in 2014?

Comment: because my application is in asp.net2.0

Comment: ASP.NET 2 came out about a decade after HTML 4. My opinion of ASP.NET just dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Use `_blank` instead in `window.open()`

Ex: `window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')`

Answer (score 1):

All modern browsers block `window.open()` calls except when they are called in response to a user event (such as a click).

Since your one is called during the page load process, it is not in response to a user event.